# Apply ZipWithIndex on a RDD of key-value pairs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a RDD of key-value pairs like `RDD[Int,String]` and I want to apply zipWithIndex for each key. Is there a way to do this?

For example if I have a RDD of kvPairs like

```
(0,10),(0,20),(0,30),(0,40),(1,11),(1,21),(1,31),(1,41) ...
```

I want the output to be like

```
((0,10),1),((0,20),2),((0,30),3),((0,40),4),
((1,11),1),((1,21),2),((1,31),3),((1,41),4) ...
```

The RDD can have any key-value combination. First I want to apply `sortByKey` and then `zipWithIndex` as above.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
rdd
  .groupByKey
  .flatMap{case (k, vs) => 
     vs
       .toList
       .sortBy(_.toInt) // Assuming this is expected order
       .zipWithIndex
       .map{case (v, i) => ((k, v), i + 1)}
  }
```